# How to retrieve recurring costs using Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to specify when a cost is first incurred and a repeat period in years that means the cost is incurred again and again. So I have created a Cost model that looks like this:

```
public class Cost
{
    public Cost()
    {
        Year = 1;
    }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int AnsweredQuestionID { get; set;}

    public virtual AnsweredQuestion AnsweredQuestion {get; set;}

    public int? RepeatPeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to return the costs incurred between two dates, preferably using Linq.

**Edit** I oversimplified my question. I have PropertyCosts that are incurred on a specific Date and again after a period of time. The date the cost is first incurred is calculated from the date the property was surveyed. The costs model stores the RepeatPeriod and is related to a specific Question/Answer. The cost is incurred if a question has been answered in a specific way for a property. So I've got code that looks a bit like this (still trying to simplify here) but at the moment I'm only getting the first occurences

```
    public IEnumerable<PropertyCost> GetCosts(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
       IQueryable<AnsweredQuestion> answeredQuestions = 
                           _Uow.AnsweredQuestionRepository
                               .All
                               .Where(x => x.PropertySurvey.PropertyID == id);
       IQueryable<Cost> allCosts = UOW.CostRepository.All;

       IQueryable<PropertyCost> firstOccurences = from aq in answeredQuestions
              from c in costs
              where aq.ID == c.AnsweredQuestionID
              select new PropertyCost
              {
                  QuestionText = aq.Question.Text,
                  AnswerText = aq.Answer.Text,
                  UnitCost = c.Amount,
                  Date = aq.PropertySurvey.Survey.StartDate,
                  RepeatYears = c.RepeatPeriod
              });
       //but now I need to insert PropertyCosts for recurring costs that occur when RepeatPeriod is not null

    }
```

Comment: You mean you want to find the dates between startDate and endDate that `FirstIncurred + n * RepeatPeriod` happen? Why's that a `Cost` as a return? And it might be better if you include Years in the name of RepeatPeriod so it's obvious what the units are.

Comment: For the actual calculation: you could take the FirstIncurred date and then `addYears(RepeatPeriod)` until it's `>= startDate`; then output the date, add RepeatPeriod and repeat output and add whilst it's still `<= endDate`. For LINQ you can do this as a `yield`.

Comment: You are attempting to return a collection of `Cost` but your model does not appear to be structured as such.  Do you have a `Cost` object for each occurrence?

Comment: @Rup I tried to simplify my Model to make the question easier to understand but I realise now it no longer makes sense. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this....

```
var costs = firstOccurences.SelectMany (p => 
           from x in Enumerable.Range(0, (p.RepeatYears ?? 0) > 0
                               ? ((endDate.Year - p.Date.Year)+1)/p.RepeatYears.Value
                               : 1)
        let date = p.Date.AddYears(x * p.RepeatYears??0)
        where startDate <= date && endDate >= date
        select new PropertyCost {
          QuestionText=p.QuestionText,
          AnswerText=p.AnswerText,
          UnitCost = p.UnitCost,
          Date = date,
          RepeatYears = p.RepeatYears
        }
    )
```

You may need to convert firstOccurences to an Enumerable first due to translations functions

eg

```
          IEnumerable<PropertyCost> firstOccurences = (from aq in answeredQuestions
          from c in costs
          where aq.ID == c.AnsweredQuestionID
          select new PropertyCost
          {
              QuestionText = aq.Question.Text,
              AnswerText = aq.Answer.Text,
              UnitCost = c.Amount,
              Date = aq.PropertySurvey.Survey.StartDate,
              RepeatYears = c.RepeatPeriod
          }).AsEnumerable();
```

It's a quick fix and the initial `0` from the `Enumerable.Range` could be replaced with a calculation.

Comment: That appears to be it! I removed the startDate variable because it does not exist and in the finished version I use a list of anonymous objects for firstOccurences then project that to a list of PropertyCost objects that no longer have a "RepeatYears" property. Many thanks.

Comment: I discovered a minor bug here. `((endDate.Year - p.Date.Year)+1)/p.RepeatYears.Value` should be `((endDate.Year - p.Date.Year) / p.RepeatYears.Value) + 1` otherwise the "count" parameter to Enumerable.Range can be zero and you lose the first occurence

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I have no idea why would you like to return collection of `Cost` items. You should create another `class` to handle that data, e.g.:

```
public class CostOccurrence
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Occurrence { get; set; }
}
```

And then implement your method:

```
public IEnumerable<CostOccurrence> GetCosts(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DateTime current = FirstIncurred;

    while (current < startDate)
        current = current.AddYears(RepeatPeriod);

    while (current >= startDate && current < endDate)
    {
        yield return new CostOccurrence { Amount = Amount, Occurrence = current };
        current = current.AddYears(RepeatPeriod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marcin, I have now edited my question to make it clearer what I am trying to achieve. Given an IQueryable of PropertyCosts with a repeat period I need to get a list of PropertyCosts (or PropertyCostOccurrences if you prefer) that includes repeats